# pgAdmin III Server doesn't listen

Tags: postgresql-9.3, pgadmin

I'm aware that this issue has been asked multiple times, but after searching for hours and trying multiple solutions, nothing has worked for me.

Issue: I cannot connect remotely to my postgresql-9.3 server using pgAdmin III.

The postgres server is on RHEL6 and pgAdmin GUI is on Windows. 
pg_hba.conf file:
I've just ended up allowing all connections until I figure out the issue.

```
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

postgres.conf file:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
max_connections = 100
```

I have restarted the server, and don't have a password on my postgres user.
I can access the server locally, but not remotely.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
After running netstat

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      26369/postmaster
```

Comment: If you connect to the external ip of the server from the local server? Let's say, the server h as ip 192.168.0.100, can  you connect to that when you are on the server itself?

Comment: Just tried it and yes I can.

Comment: If that works most likely it's something firewall related.

Comment: Strange. I've gotten this to work before I did not have to change any firewall settings on either side.

Comment: It was a firewall issue. Turned off the firewall on my VM and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Firewall issue. Turned off firewall and remote connection worked fine.

Comment: Note that simply disabling a firewall is only a quick measure to see if that was the problem. It's better to find a way to enable postgres to work through the firewall than simply disable it due to security.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I plan on circumventing this issue soon.