# MACOS 10.13.6 - PG Admin 4 | Server not listening

Tags: sql, pgadmin-4

I tried to install PgAdmin4 for the second time on my MacBook but it don't want to connect to the localhost database "PostgresSQL 10".

On PG4 I've got this error :

> Could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

I used terminal command : `netstat -ap tcp | grep -i "listen"` and got this result :

> tcp4       0      0  localhost.52065        *.*                    LISTEN
>   tcp6       0      0  *.49335                *.*                    LISTEN
>   tcp4       0      0  *.49335                *.*                    LISTEN
>   tcp4       0      0  localhost.ipp          *.*                    LISTEN
>   tcp6       0      0  localhost.ipp          *.*                    LISTEN
>   tcp46      0      0  *.5557                 *.*                    LISTEN
>   tcp46      0      0  *.freeciv              *.*                    LISTEN
>   tcp46      0      0  *.10134                *.*                    LISTEN
>   tcp46      0      0  *.nfsd-status          *.*                    LISTEN
>   tcp4       0      0  *.nfsd-status          *.*                    LISTEN

So I tried to install PG3 and see the difference but it's just show me the same error in a "document" version with the title "Serveur not listening" with all the details. I've found somethere that I have to change the file "pg_hba.conf " but I can't found it on the files of the application.

On this topic : [pgAdmin III Server doesn't listen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217600/pgadmin-iii-server-doesnt-listen) they talk about firewall issue but I don't use one.

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: @Slumdog no... and I’ve got this problem when I add à new server :/

Answer (score 0):

Oh ok, it sounds a bit confusing because if you have one instance of Postgresql running the default install port is 5432. You should add a postgresql tag to your issue I don't think it's PGadmin. 
Have you been able to connect to Postgresql by any means? Just wondering, it will make it easier to sort if you do have access. I'm on Win 10 but possibly if your Postgresql is installed but not running currently you should try starting it;

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

You will probably need to edit pg_hba.conf once you are sure it has started. You might find it at /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf  but before that you will find postgresql.conf at the same location and that file will contain the listen port #.
Try this out and report back please, good luck